# PHP conditional statement using $_SESSION assigns value, but why?

Tags: php, session, conditional-statements

I actually found out how to solve this particular problem on my own, but it's still driving me crazy wondering why the problem came about to begin with. I had a conditional statement:

```
if($_SESSION['authenticated'] = 1) {
    DOSTUFF;
}
```

Now prior to this if statement I know that `$_SESSION['authenticated']` is empty by using `print_r()`. However, after executing this code block this conditional statement assigns 1 to `$_SESSION['authenticated']`, which makes the if statement evaluate to true no matter what! I found a way around this using `isset()`, but I still have no clue why a conditional statement would assign a value to a variable in the first place when it should only evaluate whether or not the condition is true or false.

Comment: `if($_SESSION['authenticated'] == 1) {` you're doing an assignment instead of a comparison

Comment: Looks like someone beat us both @JohnConde lol but I've got 7!

Comment: I type at more than 70 WP/M (*90 on a good day*), probably why I was first @JohnConde Time to grease that there keyboard of yours or put some fancy racing stripes, just like ADIDAS, they went faster! ;-)

Comment: I type about 7 words per minute. I am the *worst* typer ever. Whenever someone watches me code I always tell them to ignore my fingers. Just focus on the results!

Comment: You've a point there. Quality before quantity ;-) I've been blessed with both (*blowing on fingers*) lol @JohnConde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `=` is assignment.  You want `==` or `===` which test for equality.  `===` checks that the operands are both equal and of the same type.  `==` only checks for equality.

Comment: I've got 3 upvotes lol but will +1 ;-) why not, it's almost the weekend.

Comment: Scratch that, I'm up to 7. But I'll keep the upvote intact. ;-)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty basic. I feel like an idiot.. I definitely need to take a break. I've spent so much time at the computer my brain is mush. Thanks guys.. you've saved my sanity at least. I was so baffled.

Comment: @user3479482 This is unfortunately one of those "allowed but questionable" constructs that appear in many languages. (If I designed a language that allowed assignments in/as expressions, explicit wrapping parenthesis would be required for a valid production.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a semantic <strike>(or syntactic)</strike> (or typing) error. You should use double equal sign for equality comparison like this:

```
if($_SESSION['authenticated'] == 1) {
    DOSTUFF;
}
```

If you use single equality sing, that means assignment, and the assigned value gets evaluated in the if statement.